# "z-index" of mesh materials, how could I fix?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I know there are two settings for each material in my JSON model: `depthTest` and `depthWrite`.

I set them to `false`, because some materials have RGBA textures images and with true all the alpha channel becomes of the same color of the background.

Now textures have something like a `z-index` value that place them above or below.

How could I fix it?

EDIT:
Here's the page: http://xalien95.altervista.org/pkmnxy_engine/alisopoli.html
Here's the code:

```
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, loader;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
            camera.position.z = 1000;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

            loader.load( "alisopoli/alisopoli.js", function( geometry, materials ) {
                for ( var i = 0; i < materials.length; i ++ ) {
                    materials[ i ].side = THREE.DoubleSide
                    //materials[ i ].overdraw = true;
                }
                //var faceMaterials = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
                //faceMaterials.map.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
                //mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, faceMaterials );
                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
                mesh.scale.set( 100, 100, 100 );
                mesh.rotation.x = 45 * Math.PI / 180;
                scene.add( mesh );
            } );


            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF);
            scene.add(ambientLight);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            mesh.rotation.y += 0.005;

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
```

Here's the model: http://xalien95.altervista.org/pkmnxy_engine/alisopoli/alisopoli.js

Comment: I edited the question with page, code and model.

Comment: Sidenote: your Altervista page is missing an index. Unless they've changed the rules, it is against their TOS to host unindexed files. Still, they won't do anything but I'd recommend to upload a dummy 'under construction' page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my question.
What I did with depthTest and depthWrite is not correct.
I needed to only edit **alphaTest**.